# Nothing is visible on webpage other than CSS Wave Animation

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and wanted to use this wave animation I found - https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/QMwObb

After applying it in HTML file only the CSS animation is visible and the Text content and other stuff is not visible.
I guess it is overlapped by the CSS animation but I am not sure what should I do.

index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <div class="waveWrapper waveAnimation">
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgTop">
          <div class="wave waveTop" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgMiddle">
          <div class="wave waveMiddle" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgBottom">
          <div class="wave waveBottom" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
@keyframes move_wave {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0) scaleY(0.55)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
}

.waveWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.waveWrapperInner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #86377b 20%, #27273c 80%);
}
.bgTop {
    z-index: 15;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.bgMiddle {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.bgBottom {
    z-index: 5;
}
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.waveTop {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveTop {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.waveMiddle {
    background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveMiddle {
    animation: move_wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.waveBottom {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveBottom {
    animation: move_wave 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Um... Can you at least add a screenshot of it?

Comment: please create a JSFiddle or sth like that where someone can run your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index:-999;` To `.waveWrapper{}`

A Simple Solution To Your Problem :)

Demo ->

```css
@keyframes move_wave {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0) scaleY(0.55)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
}

.waveWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:-999; /* Added Here */
}
.waveWrapperInner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #86377b 20%, #27273c 80%);
}
.bgTop {
    z-index: 15;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.bgMiddle {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.bgBottom {
    z-index: 5;
}
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.waveTop {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveTop {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.waveMiddle {
    background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveMiddle {
    animation: move_wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.waveBottom {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveBottom {
    animation: move_wave 15s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <div class="waveWrapper waveAnimation">
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgTop">
          <div class="wave waveTop" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgMiddle">
          <div class="wave waveMiddle" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="waveWrapperInner bgBottom">
          <div class="wave waveBottom" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution for you:

for text tags (`<h1> & <p>`):

```
position: relative;
z-index: 999999;
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS z-index indicates how elements overlap each other.
In your case, the heading and the paragraph doesn’t have a z-index value, while the wave elements do.

So, give your `h1` and  `p` elements a z-index by something like:

```
h1 {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Just make sure the z-index is bigger than those of the waves.
Apply the same CSS to `<p>` as well.